# Iterating through a vector and cast enum to integer

Tags: rust

I have a vector of enums that I want to cast to an integer value so I can do a numerical comparison.

I keep running into borrowing warnings "cannot move out of borrowed context"

I have tried various permutations of the following:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

let values = vec![SomeEnum::A, SomeEnum::B];

for val in values.iter() {
  let i = *val as i32;
  // if i < X do something
}
```

Comment: prefer `for val in &values` in this case

Comment: @Stargateur fails with "not an iterator"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call [`values.iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter), you take a reference to the `Vec`tor as a slice because it [`impl`s `Deref<Target=[T]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#deref-methods). It returns an `Iterator` over `&T`, which is borrowed. Then, you try the following line:

```rust
let i = *val as i32;
```

There is a problem with this: `val` is of type `&SomeEnum`, and therefore you cannot move the value out of the reference, *or* copy it, because `SomeEnum` doesn't impl `Copy` or `Clone`. To solve this issue, you can choose from the following, depending on the scenario:

- `Copy` the value, by making the `enum` [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). Making it do this results in allowing rust to implicitly copy the value, bitwise.

```rust
#[derive(Copy)]
enum SomeEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}
```

- Use [`Iterator::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) extension on the iterator. This copies each value, making it so that the iterator yields `T` instead of `&T`. Note too that this is a nightly api currently, so you will have to wait a little longer for it to become stable.

```rust
#[derive(Copy)]
enum SomeEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}
let values = vec![SomeEnum::A, SomeEnum::B];

for val in values.iter().copied() {
    let i = val as i32;
}
```

- Make it clone. [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) is a trait that allows the implementor to `impl` a way to copy the data, but also perform another operation with it, in the case that simply `Copy`ing bitwise is unsafe.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
enum SomeEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}
```

- Use [`Iterator::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned). This is, once again, a similar idea to `Iterator::copied`, except it `Clone`s the objects and is stable.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
enum SomeEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}
let values = vec![SomeEnum::A, SomeEnum::B];

for val in values.iter().cloned() {
    let i = val as i32;
}
```

- Consume the `Vec`. This makes it so that you can no longer use the `Vec`, and instead each of the values is consumed in the `Vec`. This is the least flexible of the approaches, leading to you losing access to `values` because it is moved into [`into_iter(self)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#into_iter.v).

```
enum SomeEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}
let values = vec![SomeEnum::A, SomeEnum::B];

for val in values.into_iter() {
    let i = val as i32;
}
```

There are a few other ways to tackle this, but these are the simplest.

Other ways of going about this are:

- Custom `impl` of mathematical operations
- Implement a `From` trait, to make it more obvious you're converting.

Comment: Amazing. You just learned me a ton on how Rust works. I've read the docs (multiple times), but facing your own problem and understanding is really different.

Comment: for loop already do the job so call `into_iter()` is not needed

Answer (score 2):

`iter` iterates through a collection using the references to the elements. `into_iter`, which causes a move, will give you access to the actual elements. If you're okay with the move, then this can help ease the cast of enums ordinal values:

```
for val in values.into_iter() {
    let i = val as i32;
    // if i < X do something
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to iterate the vector again, you can use clone:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
enum SomeEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}
```

Which allows to cast after allocating a new instance of the enum value:

```
let values = vec![SomeEnum::A, SomeEnum::B];
for val in values.iter() {
    let i = (val.clone()) as i32;
    // if i < X do something
}
```